# agent.add() sometimes not able to give results in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am using Dialogflow to build a chatbot and I am using Axios to make some posts and get requests, but sometimes agent.add() inside that HTTP call doesn't work.

I am attaching the sample code.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

// Using some external libraries
//axios for using third party api hosted as http.
const axios = require('axios');
// xml2js for parsing xml output in response
const xml2js = require('xml2js');

const json = require('json');

// Accessing firebase admin
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

function name(agent){


                    return axios.post('http://some-api,
                        {"name": "Kyle"}).then((result) => {

                            console.log('Store datato api');
                            agent.add('What is your email id'); // Sometimes its working and sometimes its not
                            //return Promise.resolve(agent); // I tried this as well but the same issue.


                    });


  }
```

What could be appropiate changes, as I was going through all other questions on Stackoverflow, I tried returning pomise as well, but didn't work.

Comment: I am looking for help for the same, If someone knows it, please look into this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've structured your Promise incorrectly. This is the format I use to return responses that require Promises:

```
function name(agent) {
    const promise = new Promise(resolve => {

        // logic goes here

        resolve(agent.add(output));
    });
    return promise;
}
```

If this doesn't work, check other points it may be failing at - are you sure your webhook isn't failing in the POST request?

Comment: Ya, I am sure it is not failing at POST request, because while posting I am writing into google sheets and it is stored there and as well I can check out the logs which are working fine too.

I am calling such APIS in so many intents, so creating a promise and returning like this, is a good idea?

Comment: I've created Promises and returned them as shown, this hasn't caused any performance drops or failed responses. I suggest restructuring your code so your POST request is inside a Promise, resolve the Promise with `resolve(agent.add('What is your email id'));` inside your `.then()` method. Finally return the Promise **outside** of the `.then()` method

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will do it and see if it works fine.